# Blacklisting specific tags from an input format instead of whitelisting

Tags: input-formats

I need a filter for the "Full HTML" input format that allows me to strip specific tags. I want to allow all HTML tags, except the ones specified in the input format options.

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get that functionality out of the box with the [HTML Purifier](http://drupal.org/project/htmlpurifier) module.

Once you've installed the module, go to the `admin/config/content/formats` page, choose the text format you want to edit, and select the "HTMLPurifier" checkbox. In the settings below, quite a bit further down the page, you'll find the `ForbiddenElements` textarea:

[image]

That's where you need to put your disallowed tags. It's probably worth looking at the rest of the settings to make sure they match up with your expectations (there are a lot of them though, HTMLPurifier is pretty configurable).